# Generate an array of UUID's in Javascript

Tags: node.js, promise, uuid, node-uuid

Using a module such as `uuid` how could I generate the following structure.

```
[
    'd9baea4e-2436-4481-accb-7c2fe835039e',
    '60152666-8c2c-4d33-a5c8-da1dda106c5d', 
    'c4eaa558-83cc-4b94-9aff-1aefdc204794', 
    '273998e3-3138-41eb-b740-28ee53f7e344'
]
```

Would I be right in assuming this could be done with a `Promise` or at least could such an approach be given.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) is actually a synchronous function, per the docs.  So a simple loop would do:

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
const ids = [];
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
  ids.push(uuidv4());
}
```

Or you can also do a one-liner if you like:

```
const ids = Array(4).fill().map(() => uuid());
```

Comment: That one-liner is awesome!

Comment: and FP way +1 for that

Comment: That ES6 is delicious :-)